# Disable pattern caching

Tags: caching, postscript

I am writing a program that will convert a postscript file to a simpler sequence of points that I can send to a plotter I am building. I am doing this by running a bit of header code that replaces the painting operations with operations that print points to stdout, which my main control program will then use:

```
/stroke { gsave
  matrix defaultmatrix setmatrix
  flattenpath
  /str 20 string def

    {(m ) print 2 copy exch str cvs print ( ) print =}
    {(l ) print exch str cvs print ( ) print =}
    {6 {pop} repeat (error) =} % should never happen...
    {(l ) print exch str cvs print ( ) print =}
  pathforall

  grestore
  stroke
} bind def

/fill {
  gsave stroke grestore fill
} bind def
```

As a side note, I really wish postscript had a printf command, like `1 1 add (1+1=%d) printf`.

In order for this to work with fonts, I disabled font caching by setting the cache limit to 0, with `0 setcachelimit`. Otherwise, the postscript interpreter will not invoke the painting operations for subsequent uses of cached objects. I would have rather disabled font caching by redefining `setcachedevice` and `setcachedevice2` but those operators also have to handle some character metric stuff, not just the caching.

User paths can also be cached , and I was able to disable this caching by redefining `ucache` and setting the cache limit to 0 via `/ucache {} def`.

However, there does not seem to be a command for configuring the pattern cache parameters, and patterns do not need to explicitly request caching., and even if there was I would need to force it to invoke the painting operations for each and every pattern cell even within the same fill operation. **How can I disable pattern caching?**

Answer (score 2):

```
<</MaxPatternCache 0>> setsystemparams
```

Assuming that your interpreter doesn't have a password protecting the system parameters, and that it honours this system parameter.

See appendix C of the 3rd edition PLRM, especially section "C.3.3 Other Caches". You will need to consider Forms as well.

Comment: Do you know of an interpreter that will respect that parameter? I tried it with ghostscript, but it keeps caching them anyway, even between separate fill operations.

Comment: Well, I presume Adobe's CPSI does, Global Graphics' JAWS Rip also does. I have no real idea about others. If you mean a 'Free Open Source' PostScript interpreter, then I don't think there are any except Ghostscript these days (Luser Droog has one though, but I'm not sure its complete enough to deal with patterns). You cannot disable the pattern cache in Ghostscript, its fundamental to the operation of the graphics library.

Comment: You may want to consider wirting a Ghostscript device, instead of hacking the language, which would give you access to the objects instead of trying to extract them in this rather slow and painful way. Finally you could redefine makepattern and setpattern to store the pattern definition yourself. Then you can redefine setcolorspace to tile the pattern over the area yourself. How are you planning to deal with images and shadings ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt at a `printf` implementation to match your syntax.

```
/formats <<
    (d) { cvi 20 string cvs }
>> def 

% val1 val2 .. valN (format-str)  printf  -
/printf {
    0 1 index (%) { % ... (fmt) n (fmt) (%) 
        search {    % ... (fmt) n (post)(%)(pre)
            pop pop exch 1 add exch (%) % ... (fmt) n=n+1 (post) (%) 
        }{          % ... (fmt) n (rem)
            pop exit
        } ifelse
    } loop % val1 val2 .. valN (fmt) n
    dup { % ... (fmt) n
        exch (%) search pop      % ... n (post)(%)(pre)
        print pop                % ... n (post)
        exch dup                 % ... (post) n n 
        2 add -1 roll            %  .. (post) n val1
        3 1 roll 1 sub           %  .. val1 (post) n=n-1
        exch                     %  .. val1 n (post)
        dup 0 1 getinterval      %  .. val1 n (post) (p) 
        exch 1 1 index           %  .. val1 n (p) (post) 1 (post)
        length 1 sub getinterval %  .. val1 n (p) (ost)
        exch 4 -1 roll           %  .. n (ost) (p) val1
        exch //formats exch
        2 copy known not { pop /default } if get exec
        print                    %  .. n (ost)
        exch
    } repeat
    pop 
    print
} def 

1 1 add (1+1=%d) printf
```

But, if I may criticize a little, this probably isn't the best use of postscript. For one, the conversion specifiers aren't really necessary since postscript objects carry their own type info. There was a NeWS extension operator called `printf` which comes closer to the mark, I think ([ref](https://manx.classiccmp.org/details.php/26,18331)) ([pdf](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/sun/NeWS/800-4888-10_Rev_A_.NeWS_2.1_Programmers_Guide_Jun_1990.pdf)).

[image]

I know it says `sprintf` here which is a little different, but the `printf` entry just referred to this entry.